# Regarding analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I just wanted to know more about analytics. I am new to this thing. I was researching in google analytics and had a question that can I get it to work for subdomains? For example, my site is www.example.com and I am maintaining two different clients on www.example.com/myclient and www.example.com/otherclient. Is is possible to get the analytics for two sub domains? If not with google analytics, then what would be the way? Links would help as well. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not searching the [Google Analytics Help](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55524) first ?

Comment: Wow thanks. I tried to look for the help on http://support.google.com/googleanalytics but did not reach here. Many thanks, BG.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be hard.

Set up each client with a GA account (you don't want to use the same account for both because if you make them an admin of their own GA data they will be able to see all the GA data in the same account).

You would define one "property" for each.  Each property would have a unique tracking code.

Make sure that the tracking code for the "myclient" shows up on every page that you want that client to be able to track nowhere else.  Make sure that the tracking code for "otherclient" shows up on every page that you want that client to be able to track and nowhere else.